# abstract class type but everything definied

Tags: c++, qt, abstract-class

I am currently writing a version of the travelling salesman Problem for a university classusing qt. In order to place cities on a QGraphicsView Widget I created this Programm just like in this YouTube tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgDd2QspuDg

Sadly I just make everythink like in the Tutorial, but only I get the error that my class is Abstract, which I dont understand, because everything I put in this class I define in the Code an there is Nothing unreferenced in my class.

Dialog.h:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <iostream>
#include <QPointF>
#include "mycity.h"

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();
private slots:
    double on_Kelvin_box_valueChanged();

    double on_Iter_box_valueChanged();

    double on_Radius_box_valueChanged();

    double on_CVRatio_box_valueChanged();

    void on_resetButton_clicked();

    void on_startButton_released();

    void on_stopButton_released();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    MyCity *city;

protected:

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

mycity.h:

```
#ifndef MYCITY_H
#define MYCITY_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QDebug>
#include <string.h>

class MyCity : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    MyCity();

    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    bool Pressed;
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // MYCITY_H
```

Dialog.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <qtCore>
#include <qtGui>
#include <QPointF>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    city = new MyCity();
    scene->addItem(city);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

double Dialog::on_Kelvin_box_valueChanged()
{
    double kelvin = ui->Kelvin_box->value();
    return kelvin;
}

double Dialog::on_Iter_box_valueChanged()
{
    double iter = ui->Iter_box->value();
    return iter;
}

double Dialog::on_CVRatio_box_valueChanged()
{
    double cvRatio = ui->CVRatio_box->value();
    return cvRatio;
}

double Dialog::on_Radius_box_valueChanged()
{
    double radius = ui->Radius_box->value();
    return radius;
}

void Dialog::on_resetButton_clicked()
{
   ui->Kelvin_box->setValue(0.3);
   ui->Iter_box->setValue(10000);
   ui->CVRatio_box->setValue(2.5);
   ui->Radius_box->setValue(0.1);
}

//Wenn dieser Knopf gedrückt wird startet die Iteration
void Dialog::on_startButton_released()
{

}
//Wenn dieser Knopf gedrückt wird beendet sich die Iteration
void Dialog::on_stopButton_released()
{

}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mycity.cpp:

```
#include "mycity.h"
//Das is das Objekt 'Stadt' welches wir erzeugen in der dialog.cpp
MyCity::MyCity()
{
    Pressed = false;
    setFlag(ItemIsMovable);
}

QRectF MyCity::boundingRect() const
{
   return QRectF(0,0,20,20);
}

void MyCity::paint(QPainter *painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    //ellipse wird rot bei draufdrücken, grün bei loslassen
    QRectF rec = boundingRect();
    QBrush brush(Qt::green);
    if(Pressed)
    {
        brush.setColor((Qt::red));
    }
    else
    {
        brush.setColor((Qt::green));
    }

    painter->fillRect(rec,brush);
    painter->drawRect(rec);
}

void MyCity::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    //hier geschieht, was beim mausdruck passieren soll (stadt kreieren)
    Pressed = true;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);//überschreiben der eigentlichen mousePressEvent-funktion
}

void MyCity::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    //nur temporäre testfunktion, wird am ende nich gebraucht
    Pressed = false;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

And this is the error i get:

C:...\dialog.cpp:16: Error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MyCity'
     city = new MyCity();

Can someone help me find the error which is causing this abstract class?

EDIT:
Here is the whole error message I got from qt:

```
..\Milestone_Traveling\dialog.cpp: In constructor 'Dialog::Dialog(QWidget*)':
..\Milestone_Traveling\dialog.cpp:16:31: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MyCity'
     MyCity* city = new MyCity();
                               ^
In file included from ..\Milestone_Traveling\dialog.h:10:0,
                 from ..\Milestone_Traveling\dialog.cpp:1:
..\Milestone_Traveling\mycity.h:9:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'MyCity':
 class MyCity : public QGraphicsItem
       ^
In file included from D:\QT\5.10.1\mingw53_32\include\QtWidgets/QGraphicsItem:1:0,
                 from ..\Milestone_Traveling\mycity.h:5,
                 from ..\Milestone_Traveling\dialog.h:10,
                 from ..\Milestone_Traveling\dialog.cpp:1:
D:\QT\5.10.1\mingw53_32\include\QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:344:18: note:     virtual void QGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter*, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*)
     virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = Q_NULLPTR) = 0;
                  ^
Makefile.Debug:1144: recipe for target 'debug/dialog.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/…/build-Milestone_Traveling-Desktop_Qt_5_10_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/dialog.o] Error 1
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
15:48:32: Der Prozess "D:\QT\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 2 beendet.
Fehler beim Erstellen/Deployment des Projekts Milestone_Traveling (Kit: Desktop Qt 5.10.1 MinGW 32bit)
Bei der Ausführung von Schritt "Make"
15:48:32: Verstrichene Zeit: 00:11.
```

Comment: Please post complete error message. The only incomplete class I see here is `Ui::Dialog`

Comment: I think you need to do `MyCity* city = new MyCity` to actually get runtime polymorphism.

Comment: All the major compilers will print informational messages immediately after an error like that, listing the functions it thinks are pure virtual and causing the class to be abstract.  Please paste those also.

Comment: @ThomasLang `city` is a pointer. It looks like that line is an error message ending at "'MyCity'", followed by the quoted code starting with "city =".

Comment: Wait: Isn't it in Qt the way that inside the `MyCity` type one has to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro?
@aschepler right, thanks.

Comment: Here's a tip, use the `override` keyword when you are implementing a pure virtual function from an interface. Then the compiler will tell you if you properly did the override.

Comment: @VTT Now I added the whole error message I get

Comment: @ThomasLang I tried it, but it is still showing me same error message.

Comment: Error message describes precisely which function is not implemented in class `MyCity`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use the [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword when overriding a virtual method. If you had done so when writing `MyCity::paint`, then you'd realize that it didn't match the signature for `QGraphicsItem::paint`:

QGraphicsItem:

```
virtual void paint(QPainter*, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*) = 0;
```

MyCity:

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
```

See the difference? It's subtle, but you're missing a `const`

If you had instead written `MyCity::paint` with the `override` keyword like so:

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;
```

Then you'd get a compiler error along the lines of

> error: 'virtual void MyCity::paint(...)' marked 'override', but does not override

Comment: I love you my friend. Im know C++ for very long but started with qt just few weeks before, so thank you for the explanaition. A forgotten "const" causing such a big error… damn.